# What is the syntax of SQLAlchemy func.position() for PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to build a SQLAlchemy query using the [position()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) function. What's the correct syntax for using this to generate SQL of the form `POSITION('@' IN some_column)`?

I tried `func.position('@', MyTable.my_column)`, but that generates the SQL `POSITION('@', my_table.my_column)`, rather than using `IN`.

Comment: Not an answer, but as a workaround `func.strpos(MyTable.my_column, '@')` should work.

Comment: Thanks! Don't know how I missed `strpos()` all this time. Never liked having two ways to do the same thing, but this will work for me.

Comment: Old question, but if you post it as an answer, @Marth, I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to make `IN` an operation on the substring as a literal like this:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

q = sa.select(
    sa.func.position(sa.literal('@').op('IN')(tbl.c.my_column)
)
```

which generates this SQL when compiled

```sql
SELECT position('@' IN tbl.my_column) AS position_1 \nFROM tbl
```