# "Irregular" SQL function in SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

In SqlAlchemy ORM how can I use a SQL function which requires keywords along with arguments, for example, `POSITION(substr IN str)`. The following doesn't work:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, select
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class SomeClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'a'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name =  Column(String(50))



sel = select(SomeClass).where( POSITION('x' IN name) > 5 ) # doesn't work
```

Comment: Can the comment of this question help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30655878/what-is-the-syntax-of-sqlalchemy-func-position-for-postgresql

Comment: If you use `strpos`, then your query would be like:
`sel = select(SomeClass).where(func.strpos(SomeClass.name, 'x') > 5 )`.
Import `func` using, `from sqlalchemy import func`, or add `func` into your first import line